# Clojure: Extract field from defrecord

Tags: clojure

I would like to extract the **city** field from the **person1** the following snippet of code:

```
(defrecord Address [city state])

(defrecord Person [firstname lastname ^Address address])

(defn make-person ([fname lname city state]
               (->Person fname lname (->Address city state))))
(def person1 (make-person "Mark" "Smith" "LA" "CA"))
```

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(prn (str (:state (:address person1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use defrecord like a map. The person1 record has the following structure:

```
{:address   #ns.Address {:city "LA", :state "CA"},
 :firstname "Mark",
 :lastname  "Smith"}
```

that's why you can access the field city by:

```
 (:city (:address person1))
 ==> "LA"
```